# OptionMenu changes on second function pass Tkinter Python 2.7

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

The problem I am having is that the function below works fine on the first pass  with regards to displaying the chosen value at the top of the OptionMenu before the 'Enter' button is clicked:

[First pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx1SL.png)

However on a second pass and any future passes to the function the chosen value is not displayed at the top of the OptionMenu (although if selected it will be used) before the 'Enter' Button is pressed:

[Second etc. passes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZwxI.png)

The code is:

```
def load_create_list(self):

    self.app = Toplevel(self.parent)
    self.parent.withdraw()
    self.app.title("Rgs2")

    self.student = []
    self.student1=[]
    self.gs1=0
    self.ng1=0
    options = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"]


    self.results=[]
    self.ngg=StringVar() #for the option menu widget the variable must be a stringVar not a normal string, int etc.

    self.ng = Label(self.app, text="Number of groups")
    self.ng.grid(row=2, column=0)
    self.ngg.set("3")
    self.ng1 = OptionMenu(self.app, self.ngg, *options)

    self.ng1.grid(row=2, column=1, ipadx=10)


    for i in range(0,len(self.x3)):
        self.L1 = Label(self.app,text="Student")
        self.L1.grid(row=i+4, column=0)
        self.en = Entry(self.app)
        self.en.insert(END, self.x3[i])
        self.en.grid(row=i+4, column=1)
        self.student.append(self.en)

    self.el = int(len(self.student)+1)

    for h in range(self.el,self.el+5):

        self.L2 = Label(self.app,text="Student")
        self.L2.grid(row=h+4, column=0)
        self.em = Entry(self.app)
        self.em.grid(row=h+4, column=1)
        self.student.append(self.em)

    button=Button(self.app,text="enter",command=lambda : self.hallo2()).grid(row=h+7,column=0)
    button=Button(self.app,text="Save List",command=lambda : self.save_list2()).grid(row=h+7,column=1)
```

I have tried everything but can't understand what might be causing this issues. Any help would be gladly appreciated. Seems like very odd behaviour could it be something outside of the function that is causing the issue?

Full code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import askopenfile


class main_menu:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.myParent = parent
        self.myContainer1 = Frame(parent)
        parent.title("Random Group Sorter")
        self.myContainer1.pack()

        self.button1 = Button(self.myContainer1, command = lambda : self.hope())               
        self.button1.configure(text="Create List", height = 1, width = 20, font=("Arial", 16))
        self.button1.pack(side=TOP)
        self.button1.focus_force()

        self.button3 = Button(self.myContainer1, command = lambda : self.hope1())
        self.button3.configure(text="Load List", height = 1, width = 20, font=("Arial", 16))
        self.button3.pack(side=TOP)     

        self.button2 = Button(self.myContainer1, command = lambda : exit(), )  
        self.button2.configure(text="Exit",height = 1, width = 20, font=("Arial", 16))
        self.button2.pack(side=TOP)

    def hope(self):
        self.myParent.destroy()
        create_list()

    def hope1(self):
        self.myParent.destroy()
        load_list()

class create_list():

    def __init__(self):


        parent = Tk()


        self.parent=parent
        self.student = []
        self.student1 =[] 
        self.student2 =[] 
        self.fake_student = []     
        self.results=[]
        self.ngg = StringVar()# for the option menu widget the variable must be a stringVar not a normal string, int etc.

        self.ng = Label(text="Number of groups")
        self.ng.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.ng = OptionMenu(parent, self.ngg, "2", "3", "4", "5","6")
        self.ng.grid(row=2, column=1)

        for i in range(3,21):
            self.L1 = Label(text="Student")
            self.L1.grid(sticky=E)
            self.en = Entry(parent)

            self.en.grid(row=i, column=1)
            self.student.append(self.en)

        button=Button(parent,text="Enter",command=lambda : self.hallo()).grid(row=23,column=0)
        button=Button(parent,text="Save List",command=lambda : self.save_list()).grid(row=23,column=1)

        parent.mainloop()


    def hallo(self):

        self.gs1 = int(len(self.student))

        self.ng1 = int(self.ngg.get())# still need to use .get even though a stringvar

        for entry in self.student:
            self.student1.append(entry.get())
        self.student1 = filter(None, self.student1) 

        for i in self.student1:# this is added as there are duplicate entries in the student list if saved
            if i not in self.student2:
                self.student2.append(i)
        self.parent.destroy()

        lis_an(self.student2,self.ng1)

    def save_list(self):


        for entry in self.student:
            self.student1.append(entry.get())
        self.student1 = filter(None, self.student1) 

        import tkFileDialog
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        file_name = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(parent=root)
        root.destroy() 

        print >>file_name, "\n"
        print >>file_name, "\n".join(self.student1)

        file_name.close()


class load_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []
        self.x3 = []
        self.load_clean()
        self.root = Tk()


    def load_clean(self):#option to load an already created file, cleans unwanted info from the list

        import tkFileDialog
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        file_name = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root)
        root.destroy()

        self.x = file_name.readlines()
        file_name.close()
        x2 =self.x[:]
        for z in self.x:
            if z [0:6]== "Random" or z == '\n' or z[0:5] == "Group":
                x2.remove(z)     

        for c in range (0,len(x2)):
            v = x2[c].rstrip()# this strip spaces and \n from each list item and returns the cleaned up string
            self.x3.append(v)

        self.load_create_list()   

    def load_create_list(self):
        parent = Tk()

        self.parent=parent
        self.student = []
        self.student1=[]
        self.gs1=0
        self.ng1=0



        self.results=[]
        self.ngg = StringVar()# for the option menu widget the variable must be a stringVar not a normal string, int etc.

        self.ng = Label(text="Number of groups")
        self.ng.grid(row=2, column=0)

        self.ng = OptionMenu(parent, self.ngg, "2", "3", "4", "5", "6")
        self.ng.grid(row=2, column=1)



        for i in range(0,len(self.x3)):
            self.L1 = Label(text="Student")
            self.L1.grid(row=i+3, column=0)
            self.en = Entry(parent)
            self.en.insert(END, self.x3[i])
            self.en.grid(row=i+3, column=1)
            self.student.append(self.en)

        self.el = int(len(self.student)+1)

        for h in range(self.el,self.el+5):

            self.L2 = Label(text="Student")
            self.L2.grid(row=h+3, column=0)
            self.em = Entry(parent)
            self.em.grid(row=h+3, column=1)
            self.student.append(self.em)

        button=Button(parent,text="enter",command=lambda : self.hallo2()).grid(row=h+6,column=0)
        button=Button(parent,text="Save List",command=lambda : self.save_list2()).grid(row=h+6,column=1)
        parent.mainloop()   

    def hallo2(self):
        self.student2= []
        self.gs1 = int(len(self.student))
        self.ng1 = int(self.ngg.get())# still need to use .get even though a stringvar
        for entry in self.student:
            self.student1.append(entry.get())
        self.student1 = filter(None, self.student1) 
        for i in self.student1:# this is added as there are duplicate entries in the student list if saved
            if i not in self.student2:
                self.student2.append(i)
        self.parent.destroy()

        lis_an(self.student2,self.ng1)

    def save_list2(self):
        for entry in self.student:
            self.student1.append(entry.get())
        self.student1 = filter(None, self.student1) 

        import tkFileDialog
        root = Tk()
        root.withdraw()
        file_name = tkFileDialog.asksaveasfile(parent=root)
        root.destroy() 

        print >>file_name, "\n"
        print >>file_name, "\n".join(self.student1)

        file_name.close()




class lis_an:        
     def __init__(self,student1,ng1):
        self.student1 = student1
        self.ng1=ng1
        self.results = []
        self.randomList()

     def randomList(self): # this creates a random list of students on the course
        import random
        studentb = self.student1[:]# this is added as otherwise the student list is overwritten

        studentc = [] 
        for i in range(len(studentb)): 
            element = random.choice(studentb) 
            studentb.remove(element) 
            studentc.append(element) 
        self.student1 = studentc

        self.partition()

     def partition(self): # this creates sub list of the student list containing the groups of students

        increment = len(self.student1) / float(self.ng1)
        last = 0
        i = 1
        while last < len(self.student1):
            idx = int(round(increment * i))
            self.results.append(self.student1[last:idx])
            last = idx
            i += 1

        output(self.results, self.ng1)  

class output:
    def __init__(self, student, ng1):

        self.ng1 = ng1
        self.student = student
        self.parent = Tk()


        for item1 in range (0,len(self.student)):

            test1 = "Group " + str(item1+1)+ ":"
            v = Label(self.parent, text=test1, font=("Arial", 13))
            test = "\n".join(self.student[item1])

            w = Label(self.parent, text=test, justify = LEFT, font=("Arial", 12))
            v.pack(side="top", anchor="w")
            w.pack(side="top", anchor="w")

        button=Button(self.parent,text="Repeat",command=lambda : self.join_list()).pack(side="top", anchor="w")
        button=Button(self.parent,text="Main Menu",command=lambda : self.menu_link()).pack(side="top", anchor="w")

        mainloop()

    def join_list(self):#this function creates a new undivided version of student to feed back to lis_an
        self.parent.destroy()
        self.student = [j for i in self.student for j in i] 
        lis_an(self.student,self.ng1)

    def menu_link(self):#destroys the parent frame and returns back to main menu
        self.parent.destroy()
        main()

def main():
    parent = Tk()
    myapp = main_menu(parent)
    parent.mainloop()

main()
```

Very Simple solution to this problem. I was not defining self.ngg as a StringVar in the parent widget so:

```
self.ngg = StringVar()
```

Would cause the error, and

```
self.ngg = StringVar(self.app)
```

Solves the problem. Not quite sure why this would occur on the second and subsequent uses of the function but not the first.

Comment: What do you mean by "second pass"? Are you calling the function more than once? Why are you calling `mainloop` inside the function, or is that an error in how the code is formatting for this site? Please show a complete, _minimal_ working program: http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Second pass means the second run of the function i.e. the second time it is used. Apologies main.loop was copied accidentally. The full code is quite big would you need to see it all?

Comment: No, we do not need to see the full code. Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. We want you to create a _new_ program with just enough code to illustrate the problem. It's likely that 90% of your code is completely unrelated to the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: I have tried running the function (in isolation) repeatedly and can't seem to reproduce the same problem so it must be something outside the function. I can't seem to track down the problem and don'y have any idea where it might be so I have provided the code in full. Only been learning python for a couple of weeks. Thanks.

Comment: Start with your program as-is. Remove a line of code. Does the problem still exist? Remove another line? Problem still there? Remove another line. New problem? Put that line back and pick another line. This isn't just to make our lives easier, it helps you to understand the problem better. For example, you have three buttons in main -- do you _really_ need three buttons to cause this bad behavior? What about `save_list` -- is that needed to cause the problem? `save_list2`? etc. This is part of the process of learning.

Comment: Thanks. Just spent hours stripping the program back but can't find the code that is causing this problem. I have a feeling that it could be in the  lis_an __init__  as if it is sent back to the load_create_list  function from before here it doesn't seem to cause the error. I also wonder if there is some issue with the self.ngg StringVar(). These are both hunches though. Any solutions to try would be very welcome.

Comment: Part of the problem is likely due to how you're using `Tk()` -- a well designed Tkinter app should create exactly once instance at the start of the problem, and call `mainloop()` exactly once.  You're creating multiple instances, along with calling `mainloop` more than once, which makes it very, very difficult to understand how your program works.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I am only on my second week of this project and I have a long way to go. It is actually my first ever python program. I have learnt a massive amount from it. I will keep on improving the code so I learn more. I actually solved the problem myself as you can see in the main entry. It was something very simple! I wrongly thought a mainloop was needed for all widgets instances but it is not and I have removed them from the updated code.